# How to pass dict key List with Index in python-MySQL?

Tags: python, mysql

I am stuck in python-MySQL problem

I have following dict:

```
{'Date': '2017-09-26', 'Title': ['%Accounting%', '%Php Codeigniter job%', '%laravel developer job%', '%Angular Js Developer%'], 'Location': '%USA%'}
```

My Query is follows:

```
SELECT `id` 
FROM   `jobs` 
WHERE  Date(`jobs`.`closing_date`) >= %(Date)s 
       AND `title` LIKE %(Title)s or %(Title)s or %(Title)s or %(Title)s 
       AND ( `location_name_list` LIKE %(Location)s 
              OR `location_name_list` LIKE %(Location)s 
              OR `location_name_list` LIKE %(Location)s )
```

Now I want to insert each values of dictionary in SQL Query. 
I know how to insert single variable value. But For `Title` I want to insert title index wise.

How to insert each title in to query.
I did googling so much but Every time I end up with pass only simple list in to query but I didn't get how to pass list index in to query.

I want to execute query like following:

```
SELECT `id` 
    FROM   `jobs` 
    WHERE  Date(`jobs`.`closing_date`) >= '2017-09-26' 
           AND `title` LIKE '%Accounting%' or '%Php Codeigniter job%' or '%laravel developer job%' or '%Angular Js Developer%' 
           AND ( `location_name_list` LIKE '%USA%' 
                  OR `location_name_list` LIKE '%USA%' 
                  OR `location_name_list` LIKE '%USA%' )
```

I stuck in How to pass Title in query so I can get all title in Query. I thought about pass title with Index because its in List but I don't know how to pass list element with Index in Python MySQL query.
Please let me know.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Can you be more specific about your question? Are you trying to create queries with each Title given in the json?

Comment: @SmashGuy Thanks for Comment. Yes I need to pass all title in Query and title in dict key list. I edited Question. I hope it clarified you. If not please let me know I will give more clarification

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for a dynamic query builder, you can use join() function of list to concatenate all the element of a list with a particular delimiter. This will give you the solution, but I am not sure how pythonic the code will be.

```
data = {'Date': '2017-09-26', 'Title': ['%Accounting%', '%Php Codeigniter job%', '%laravel developer job%', '%Angular Js Developer%'], 'Location': '%USA%'}
query = 'SELECT `id` FROM   `jobs` WHERE  Date(`jobs`.`closing_date`) >= '2017-09-26' AND `title` LIKE ' + "' or '".join(data['Title']) + ' AND ( `location_name_list` LIKE "%USA%"  OR `location_name_list` LIKE "%USA%" OR `location_name_list` LIKE "%USA%" )'
```

Comment: Thanks for Answer. It works in my Query but now it gives me following error:
`not enough arguments for format string`